# How do i show image on my page depending on an IF-Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:image ID="image" runat="server" hieght="200px" width="200px"></asp:image>
```

This is what is in my Code-Behind

```
string techItem = (string)Session["techItems"];

if (techItem == "1")
{
    lblName.Text = "Sony Playstation";

    Image myImage = new Image();
    myImage.ImageUrl("image-path");

}
```

This does not seem to work though.

Comment: Does `myImage.ImageUrl("image-path")` even compile? It shouldn't, `ImageUrl` is a property, not a method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new image but not actually doing anything with it. You need to set the ImageUrl of the `<asp:Image />` control that is on your page.

Change your for to;

```
if (techItem == "1")
{
    lblName.Text = "Sony Playstation";
    image.ImageUrl = "image-path"; // this is setting the image control's ImageUrl property

}
```

You may also what to show/hide the image depending on the state otherwise and image without an image src will sometimes show a broken image icon depending on the browser you are using.